# devil not loading images with linux build

Tags: c++, c, linux, devil

I was having issues getting an image to load in to Devil so I have provided exactly how I built the libs and how I am trying to use it.

Downloaded Devel source from their [website](http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php).

```
$ unzip DevIL-1.7.8.zip
$ mkdir devil
$ cd Devil-1.7.8
+-------------------------------------------+
| Just type:                                |
| autoreconf -i                             |
| ./configure <your options here>           |
| make                                      |
| sudo make install                         |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

If I use autoreconf -i then ./configure with prefix and ilu and ilut. I get an error ..forgot.. to record it. **How important is this?** I have just not used it.

```
$ chmod +x configure
$  ./configure --prefix=/home/path/to/TestingDevil/devil --enable-ILU --enable-ILUT
$ make
$ make install
```

So at this point my library *should* be built.
I downloaded the devil [simple example](http://openil.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/openil/DevIL/examples/simple_example/) (simple.c) to TestingDevil/simple/simple.c
built it.

```
$ gcc -I ../devil/include -L ../devil/lib/ simple.c -o simple -lIL -lILU -lILUT
$ cp ../devil/lib/*.so* .
```

I have added an image (jpg) to test.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./simple image.jpg
```

> "Could not open file...exiting"

I ran the executable from the simple directory.

```
simple$ ls
```

> image.jpg   libIL.so.1.1.0  libILU.so.1.1.0  libILUT.so.1.1.0 libIL.so
>   libILU.so       libILUT.so       simple libIL.so.1  libILU.so.1
>   libILUT.so.1     simple.c

**Whats going wrong?** I am using the example from devIL, it compiles and runs fine. Just can't load any files.

My System is Ubuntu 12.10 64 with build-essential installed and other dev packages for opengl dev.

Uni System is Fedora 15(?) 32. This also has exactly the same problem after building devIL in the same way.

On my home machine I installed the package libdevel-dev and that works fine.

This question does **not** ask about opengl, purely the devIL lib and example.

Comment: If the `-L ...` is right, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` should not be required. Try running the program with `strace`, that might tell you where things go wrong.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it needs the shared object just like windows needs the devil dlls.

Comment: it does need the shared library to run, but the `-L` should provide its path. Try it.

Comment: How do you mean? I have  -L ../devil/lib/

Comment: I have installed the package libdevel-dev and that works fine. Hopefully the uni will install the fedora equvelent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you build it withjout jpg support or you do not have jpeg libs available ?

Comment: I am assuming this could be the only issue since the deb is fine.